# Does Safari browser history DB contain transition type?

Tags: safari, sqlite, browser-history

The browser history of **Safari** is stored in `~/Library/Safari/History.db` which is a regular **SQLite** database. For example, it can be viewed using [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org) or queried using [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

The database contains a table named `history_items`. This lists all *URL*'s, with their *title*, and *id* and the total number of time the website was *visited*. Another table is named `history_visits`. This lists all individual *visits*, with a *timestamp*, *id* and, possibly, information about the source which *redirected* the user to this website.

In the **Chrome** browser history, the *transition type* is also [stored](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#type-VisitItem). This notes whether the user arrived at the website via a *link*, a *reload* or whether he *typed* in the address directly. Is such transition information also available in the Safari `History.db`?

The table `history_visits` also contains integer columns named *origin*, *generation* and *attributes*. However, it is unclear to me what these mean. Is there a documentation available for the Safari browser history database?